# Receive/Transmit FIFO vs Data Registers in UART

Tags: embedded

Could you please tell me what is the difference between receive/transmit FIFO and the data register in UART?

This is the first time I develop driver code for UART and so the first time I have come across with this. I am really not able to understand the difference. Please help me!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. This place isn't a code factory. Please provide your question with sample code or what you think will work, what didn't work. It's easier for people to help if you have done some work first. Also add more related tags to make your question reach more users that may help you.

Comment: When asking about specific registers in a peripheral like a UART, it is really useful to specify the hardware platform since there are very wide variations in  the registers used by different devices.

Answer (score 4):

A FIFO (first-in-first-out) buffer in a UART is a hardware implemented queue of received or transmitted data.  You do not access the FIFO directly, instead you read or write the data register and this data is automatically read or written from the head of the queue.

A FIFO can improve link efficiency because it allows software data read/write timing to vary while maintaining streaming data on the physical link.

When the FIFO is disabled or for a UART with no FIFO, there are only two bytes of buffering - the shift-register and the data-register. For input data, if the software does not read the data register in time before new data is received, it will be overwritten and data will be lost.  Equally for transmission, if data is not written as quickly as it is transmitted, the full bandwidth and efficiency of the link may not be realised.

[image]

A FIFO is perhaps most useful on systems without deterministic real-time performamce where there may be no guarantees on timely servicing of the UART (such as a Desjktop PC running a general-purpose OS such as Windows for example), however on an embedded system where buffered interrupt driven serial I/O is used, the FIFO may not be entirely necessary for low to moderate data rates in many cases.  On microcontrollers UARTS lacking a FIFO often support DMA instead which can be more effective at managing large streaming data bursts.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write to the Transmit Data Register, the byte will go to the transmit FIFO, it will sit there until physical lines are ready to transmit.

The other way arround is the same, data come from physical lines and go to the receive FIFO, waiting the user code to collect it by reading a Received Data Register.